# Visual Studio Code Symbol View Outline for Javascript

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a tree view like the one the file explorer uses or some other kind of outline for JavaScript symbols in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: This question is closed but I think this new plugin is what you are looking for  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=patrys.vscode-code-outline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no symbols tree view right now, but you can see a list of the symbols in a file by running `Go to symbol in file...` in the command palette (or cmd+shift+o/ctrl+shift+o).